Django The included URLconf '_mod_wsgi_...' does not appear to have any patterns in it
I am a Python novice and I am trying to run a Django hello world app on Windows with Apache and mod_wsgi. The upper error message shows up with the following code:
import os
import sys
import site
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from django.http import HttpResponse

site.addsitedir("C:/Program files/python312/Lib/site-packages")

sys.path.append('C:/Users/felhasznalo/Desktop/django')
sys.path.append('C:/Users/felhasznalo/Desktop/django/todo')

settings.ROOT_URLCONF=__name__
settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
settings.SECRET_KEY = '1234'

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World!")

urlpatterns = [
    path("", hello)
]

 
application = get_wsgi_application()

As of the server, it works properly with this code:
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]

So the problem is with Django configuration I think. I am not sure how to pass configuration parameters like urlpatterns. Obviously creating global variables does not work. Any idea?


Django project should have a wsgi.py file, which is the entry point for WSGI-compatible web servers to serve your project.


Configure Apache with mod_wsgi by editing the Apache configuration files (usually httpd.conf or a dedicated site configuration file).


For urlpatterns, you should define them in a urls.py file within your Django application, not directly in the WSGI configuration.

wsgi.py
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

Apache Cpnfiguration:
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>


The os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings') did not load the module for me. I am not sure why. I tried to solve this for a day, but rather ended up with the upper code.

I have no idea what is going on. After a server restart using env variables suddenly started to work.

changes in env is not recognised by server you need to restart whenever you make changes to env
